# extract file from hdfs in centos to ms-excel using power query

Tags: excel, hadoop, powerquery

i have downloaded power query in excel.and in option from hdfs it is asking for server hostname..it is localhost..But then it is giving the following error:

DataSource.Error: HDFS cannot connect to server 'localhost'. Unable to connect to the remote server.
Details:
    http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/

I have enabled webhdfs in hdfs-site.xml as follows:

> dfs.replication
>       1      
>       dfs.block.size
>       67108864
>
> dfs.webhdfs.enabled
>           true

***Help me out..how to do this..i am stuck***

Comment: It sounds like your HDFS server isn't running on your computer on port 50700. If you have `curl` installed, on the command line you would want `curl http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/` to return something, instead of an error like "couldn't connect." Are you sure the server is running on port 50700?

Comment: yes..i was using wrong port number..Thanks...:)